# Can we change the Zone Names in Orchard CMS Themes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I have noticed that in every theme I have examined from the Gallery and elsewhere, the Zone Names from the Theme Machine are used, sometimes when the Zone names make little sense.

Are there any internal dependencies that make use of those particular Zone names necessary or recommended.

Are there any consequences or difficulties introduced if those Zone names are changed when I create a new Theme?

In response to Piotr's answer:

So most of the Zone names are being recycled for convenience so that one custom theme can be based on a previous custom theme (both based on Theme Machine).

So is the zone-placement-admin-widget-zone-layer-assignment stuff tying up design efforts with a sort of convention tied to the Theme Machine zone names because of the configuration efforts imposed by the developer work patterns?

I notice that you and others are suggesting solutions based on code-over-convention to enable placing content programmatically, even using styles from another theme.

Does this mean that Orchard is moving toward a 'widget component' with a more well-rounded capability to live anywhere within the framework and compose itself nicely wherever we want to put it?

Comment: Ok, I noted Piotr's answer but, for me, there's a lot to this iceberg and I'd like to get at least most of it above water and reviewable in one place. So I updated my post with my next logical question.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly. There are no consequences - these names can be anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can name your zone names whatever you find suitable without any consequences. You should only keep the `Content` one, as it's where Orchard puts content items' main content by default.

Zones specified in Theme.txt are used for widgets admin UI only - to display a list you can choose from.
If you rename/remove a zone that currently contains some widgets, those widgets will appear in the Widgets admin "orphaned" section so you can re-assign them to new zones later on.

*Theme developers usually use the same zone names as in The Theme Machine purely for convenience. It's easier to switch themes as you don't have to move widgets around afterwards.*

Comment: Ease of theme switching is a big reason for me. So I stick to the convention unless I have a good reason not to.